# List of problems that are in general NP-hard but have polynomial-time solution in planar graphs?

Tags: algorithm, graph, np-complete, np-hard, planar-graph

I encountered many problems that can be formulated as graph problem.
It is in general NP-hard but sometimes the graph can be proved to be planar.
Hence, I am interested in learning these problems and the algorithms.

So far as I know:

1. Max cut in planar graphs
2. Four-coloring in planar graphs
3. Max Independent Set in **cubic** planar graphs

Hope someone can complete this list.

Comment: I think this belongs to cstheory.se

Comment: Looking at their [FAQ](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/faq), I think cstheory.se would probably close this.

Comment: I had closed this because it seems like a "List of X" question, but I'm reopening in hopes that there's one resource with the answer.  If others feel there's no one right answer they can vote to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this [compendium](http://www.nada.kth.se/~viggo/wwwcompendium) of NP-complete problems, under **planar** in the [index](http://www.nada.kth.se/~viggo/wwwcompendium/node276.html) there are a good number (~25) of entries.  These entries typically link to problems where planar input admits a PTAS.